# RDS AMAZON - Dificuldades para conectar no Banco de dados

Tags: sql-server, amazon-aws

Criei uma instância de banco de dados *Sql* server na Amazon, contudo não consigo conectar pelo *Sql* Server Management Studio.

Recebo a mensagem:

> erro 10060 
>   Não é possível conectar-se a endereço do endpoint,1433.

Estou utilizando os seguintes dados:

Nome do servidor o endereço do `endpoint, 1433`.
Login e senha informados no campo Master `Username` e `password` na hora de criar a instância.

Realmente não sei, o que precisa ser feito.
Alguém saberia?

Comment: Você já checou se seu IP está no grupo de segurança? Acredito que a Amazon já coloca o IP que você estava usando nesse grupo no momento da criação do banco. Caso você tenha adquirido outro IP terá que ir lá e adicionar.

Comment: meu ip da minha rede?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Essa página](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.SQLServer.html) explica tudo. Para conectar do seu PC à sua instância no RDS, você precisa saber:

- O *endpoint* da instância, algo como: `meu-rds-sql-server.abcdefgh123.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`
- O *port* do endpoint. O default é `1433` mas é bom confirmar nas propriedades de sua instância RDS.
- O *login/senha*
- Seu *[IP público](https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip)*

Para acessar seu DB vindo de fora do AWS você precisa habilitar o acesso público (ou usar VPC.) Só que você também não pode simplesmente deixar o seu DB assim, exposto para a internet toda. Então é bom colocar um Security Group que só permita acesso *Inbound* vindo de seu endereço IP.

Inspecione as propriedades de sua instância no AWS Console do RDS. Lá tem o endpoint, port, login, etc. Em particular, inspecione os Security Groups associados à sua instância. Modifique ou adicione um Security Group para permitir que apenas seu IP tenha acesso à sua instância.

Com tudo isso ajustado você deve conseguir acessar seu DB a partir de seu PC.

Comment: Eu fiz tudo isso e não consegui conectar.
- Setei o endpoint, porta, login/senha.
- Criei o inbound para o security group com o meu ip público. E nada!